# Number Conversion in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a requirement where I convert an ID (decimal example, 536879311820 )  and display in SSRS table after conversion using expression builder as shown in the figure.[image]

The rule for conversion is like this:

- Convert the number to Hexadecimal and take right 8 digits
  (536879311820 to 00802BCC)
- Convert the taken 8 digits to decimal and take right 5 digit
  (00802BCC to 8399820)

So 536879311820 should be displayed in report as 99820.  I tried up to the following expression in the expression builder,

```
=Right(HEX(Fields!PersonId.Value), 8)
```

Since the result of this expression is hexadecimal number as string, I can't find any function in common functions category in expression builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to format the string as hex after you get the last 8 characters:

```
=CDec("&H" + Right(Hex(536879311820), 8))
```

Comment: @RotatingWheel please mark it as answered if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done in SQL. Here is some code which will do it for you. I've included two additional columns so you can see how the final column was computed:

```
SELECT  CAST(123456789 AS VARBINARY(8)) HexValue, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(123456789 AS VARBINARY(8)),2) AS VARCHARHEX, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(123456789 AS VARBINARY(8)),2),5) AS Last5Chars
```

Comment: I am building report, so where should I use the code? In Query Designer? Can I do it in the way I was targeting?

Comment: Add this code to your dataset - e.g. in your view or stored procedure. If the SQL is stored within your report I would recommend getting it into the DB anyway for maintainability.